# Mouse over image turns into 2 seperate boxes

Tags: jquery, mouse, onmouseover

I'm looking for an effect I found on this page:
https://www.rentitb.com/

It's one photo with title, and then when you mouse-over it, it changes into 2 images with titles and links...

On that page, if you mouse over this:

[image]

You see this:

[image]

What is the name of this effect ?
How do i do it ?
Is there any example online ?

Comment: just one div .. put inside it two divs .. one for single image and one for two images .. and use hover in css to display one to none and another to block or use jquery to do that

Comment: Is there any example or tutorial on how to do that ?

Comment: start from here http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/enfwvtyb/

Comment: Thank you so much ! Iv'e changes it and now it's 100% what i wanted!

Comment: glad to hear that .. Good Luck :)